# Dataload Error - Insert failed, Can Upsert work?

Tags: insert, bulkinsert, dataloader, data-scrubbing, apex-data-loader

I was doing an insert dataload yesterday and some of the records failed. I still need to insert about 1300 ids. Is it possible to do an upsert now for the same file? I dont want to sort the ones that are already inserted. The error file is quite consfusing so i was wondering if I could do an Upsert now? TIA

Tried an Insert.

Expected : Data Inserted

Comment: Well, if it didn't like the data on insert, it will probably not like it on upsert either. But after you've cleaned up the data, either insert or upsert should work. Hard to tell for sure without knowing why records got rejected, though.